# Bootstrap Responsive affix

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, sidebar, affix

I need to sidebar box affix fix top, but problem with responsive.
Thanks for advice or example.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <!-- sidebar affix -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-content">
        <!-- content sidebar -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please be much more clear about what's not working, and edit your question title to reflect that.

Comment: Do you look this page sidebar right "Mer informasjon?" it works responsive. So I need like this
http://odin.reaktortest.no/hvorfor-velge-fixit/